# Binding data with Spring MVC form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

So far I am able to bind the user input data from the front end by using form binding(with POJOs). For example, I can bind

`<input type="number" name="age" />`

by creating method in the controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@RequestParam("age") Integer age) {}
```

Now I have something like this:

```
<input type="number" name="yourAge" />
<input type="number" name="myAge" />
<p name="ageDifference"> </p>
```

Here, I wrote some java script to simply calculate the age difference by substracting `yourAge` and `myAge`, and the `ageDifference` will automatically shows up in the `<p>` paragraph.What I really want to do is bind the output, i.e. `ageDifference` to the controller. I am thinking something like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@RequestParam("ageDifference") Integer ageDifference) {}
```

But when I run it, I do not think spring is able to bind the data, this is a simplified question, I tried to save the data into database, but got HTTP 400 error:

> Required String parameter 'ageDifference' is not present
>
> description: The request sent by the client was syntactically
> incorrect.

Is this doable? Or am I in the completely wrong direction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it as a hidden variable and you will get it in java
to make a variable hidden ,you simply need to change your code

to hidden by using below example,.same will be need to change in java Controller also,the name  ageDifferencehidden

```
 <input type="hidden" name="ageDifferencehidden" value=${ageDifference}/>
```